# Ошибка импорта py-файла

Tags: python

У меня имеется файл parser.py в котором находятся методы.
В другом файле мне нужно вызвать некоторые методы из первого файла.
Оба файла лежат в одной папке.

```
import parser
professions = parser.get_professions()
parser.main_parse(current_region)
```

Кидает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/trudvsem.ru/parser_region.py", line 50, in <module>
    professions = parser.get_professions()
AttributeError: module 'parser' has no attribute 'get_professions'.
```

Почему он не видит?

При чем я уже сcылался таким образом и все работало. Например:

**core.py**

```
def get_html (request):
    return BeautifulSoup(request, 'lxml')


def request(url, header, data=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=header, params=data)
    return r
```

**parser**

```
import core
r = core.request(url, header, data)
html = core.get_html(r.text)


def get_professions():
    print("Загрузка списка профессий")
    sql = """SELECT name FROM profession"""
    professions = []
    response = core.database_request(config, sql, None)
    for profession in response:
        professions.append(profession[0])


return professions
```

Может ли это из-за конструкции
`if __name__ == '__main__':,` который имеется в `parser.py`, но отсутствует в `core.py`

Comment: так, ошибка в том, что в parser, нет атрибута get_professions, вам нужно, просто-напросто его создать

Comment: @JackWolf я хочу вызвать метод, который имеется в этом файле

Comment: Переименуй название, ибо parser у Python есть такой модуль